# beginner ESRI Javascript API Question

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

So I've just finished the tutorial to at least get a map on the screen, and it already isn't working. Can someone see what I'm missing?[image: htmlfile][image: javascriptfile]

Comment: how are you accessing your webmap? Are you just calling the C:\\path\to\app?

Comment: I think you should edit your Question to include a link to the tutorial you are working through and use the Code formatting button to include the text (rather than image) of your code.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jstutorials/intro_firstmap.html) to the tutorial. I don't have a web server yet, I need to design it before it goes online.

Answer (score 1):

attempting to load an external .js file in a script tag via file protocol is a problem

```
<script src="C:\Users\mottesen\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SF_IM\SF_IM\My Project\SF_IM.js"></script>
```

try using either an http path or a relative path instead.

additionally, as noted in the help, loading your own application in the browser via http (as opposed to using file protocol) is mandatory as well.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_devenv.html

Answer (score 1):

You should probably scrap your local .js file, as John pointed out. Just write the code in the main HTML file. Since you're just starting out, you should try to get used to writing in [the new AMD style](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_dojo_amd.html) since you're using the 3.8 API.

```
<script>
  var map;
  require(["esri/map", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(esriMap, parser) {
      parser.parse();
      map = new esriMap("mapDiv", {
        center: [56.049, 38.485],
        zoom: 3,
        basemap: "streets"
      });
    }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Is putting `map` in the global namespace really necessary?

Comment: Probably not, but just about every ESRI sample does it.

Comment: @blah238 I put the map in the global namespace because I then do not need to define it in everyone of my widgets.